# Are there predicate functions to compare mpfr_t with double?

Tags: mpfr

There are predicate functions to compare `mpfr_t` with `mpfr_t`. For example:

```
int mpfr_greaterequal_p (mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2)
int mpfr_lessequal_p (mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2)
```

Are there predicate functions to compare `mpfr_t` with `double`? For example:

```
int mpfr_greaterequal_p_d (mpfr_t op1, double op2)
int mpfr_lessequal_p_d (mpfr_t op1, double op2)
```

If no, then:

1. Why?
2. What's the most efficient way to perform, for example, `mpfr_t >= 2.0` comparison?

---

Extra: per my experience, systems / ISAs / FP implementations may provide only three predicates: `==`, `<=` (or `>=`), `<` (or `>`), because they are sufficient. As I see, MPFR provides at least five predicates: `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `==`. A simple question: then why there is no `!=` predicate (e.g. `mpfr_unequal_p`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no predicates to compare `mpfr_t` with `double`, mainly because they have not been added. Note that mixed operations with `double` are there to potentially make the use of MPFR a bit easier. But they are not more efficient, because the `double` argument is typically converted to a MPFR number first. For instance, see the [current implementation of `mpfr_cmp_d`](https://gitlab.inria.fr/mpfr/mpfr/-/blob/2204aac3e9a9aebc3525dbae9061f5970702a556/src/cmp_d.c), which does a conversion and uses `mpfr_cmp`.

Note that 3 predicates are not sufficient due to *unordered* (caused by NaN). The 4 mutually exclusive relations (*less than*, *equal*, *greater than*, and *unordered*) give 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 possibilities. So one needs 7 predicates (to avoid the need of combinations of 2 predicates): with a NOT, one gets 2 × 7 = 14 predicates, and the remaining 2 predicates *true* and *false* are useless. MPFR provides such 7 predicates: `mpfr_greater_p`, `mpfr_greaterequal_p`, `mpfr_less_p`, `mpfr_lessequal_p`, `mpfr_equal_p`, `mpfr_lessgreater_p`, `mpfr_unordered_p`.

To quote [comparisons.c](https://gitlab.inria.fr/mpfr/mpfr/-/blob/2204aac3e9a9aebc3525dbae9061f5970702a556/src/comparisons.c):

```
/*                          =     <     >     unordered
 * mpfr_greater_p           0     0     1     0
 * mpfr_greaterequal_p      1     0     1     0
 * mpfr_less_p              0     1     0     0
 * mpfr_lessequal_p         1     1     0     0
 * mpfr_lessgreater_p       0     1     1     0
 * mpfr_equal_p             1     0     0     0
 * mpfr_unordered_p         0     0     0     1
 */
```

If you take the negation of `mpfr_unordered_p`, you get (1,1,1,0). So you have every combination of (x,y,z,0) except the useless (0,0,0,0). The combinations of (x,y,z,1), except the useless (1,1,1,1), are obtained by taking the NOT of the result.

Comment: Consider `A < B`. Why use `mpfr_less_p(A, B)` if `A < B` can be implemented using `mpfr_greater_p(B, A)`? Do I miss something? Extra: to remind: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use" (C11, 7.1.3p1). The `mpfr.h` has identifiers which violate this rule.

Comment: Extra question: any plans to add support of Von Neumann rounding? FYI: ARMv8's pseudocode support it as `FPRounding_ODD`.

Comment: @pmor It's in the TODO. However, this isn't really useful in MPFR for 2 reasons: MPFR already supports mixed precision, and even without mixed precision, Von Neumann rounding (a.k.a. sticky rounding) is made useless by the ternary value, which serves as the sticky bit. And thanks to the latter reason, you can already emulate this rounding mode by using `MPFR_RNDZ` and the ternary value.